# How to only plot a specific value of a categorial dataset using pcolormesh

Tags: matplotlib, categorical-data, colormap, cartopy, color-mapping

I am trying to plot categorial precipitation type and I have a colormap I want to use as the array either includes -0.99 (no precip) or 0.99 (precip). I want to know how to only plot when the data is equal to 0.99. Currently this is the code I am trying and it is just plotting my whole map pink. Is there a better way to do this?

```
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib import colors
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

proj = ccrs.LambertConformal(central_longitude=cLon, 
central_latitude=cLat)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,12),dpi=100) # Increase the dots per inch from default 100 to make plot easier to read
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1,projection=proj)
ax.set_extent ([lonW,lonE,latS,latN])

ptype_colors_fzra = ['deeppink']
cmap_ptype_ext_fzra = mpl.colors.ListedColormap(ptype_colors_fzra)
norm_ptype_ext_fzra = mpl.colors.BoundaryNorm([0.98,1],ncolors = len(ptype_colors_fzra))

ax.contourf(lons, lats, cfzra, cmap = cmap_ptype_ext_fzra, norm = norm_ptype_ext_fzra, 
transform = ccrs.PlateCarree(), zorder = 2)
```

This is what ends up plotting

[image]

Comment: Please edit your code to include imports so that your issue is replicable.

Comment: @YaakovBressler just added them now

Comment: This question is not reproducible without **data**. This question needs a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Always provide a [mre] **with code, data, errors, current output, and expected output, as [formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)**. If relevant, plot images are okay. If you don't include an mre, it is likely the question will be downvoted, closed, and deleted.